# Angular 2 - autoLoad custom event

Tags: angular, custom-events

I have problem with a part of my application.

In my html I need to launch somes method `arrayContains` to detect something.
How can I launch my method directly from html (without click, mouse enter etc)?

I have tried a custom event but it is not working.

This is my html file:

```
<div class="LG_global-wrap" (autoLoad)="arrayContains('a string')"></div>
```

this is my ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'something',
  templateUrl: './something.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./something.component.scss']
})
export class somethingComponent implements OnInit  {
  public dataType;
  @Output('autoLoad') initEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.somethingService.getSomething().subscribe((elem) => {
      this.dataType = elem.data;
      this.initEvent.emit();
    });
  }

  public arrayContains(needle) {
    console.log('needle: ', needle);
  }

}
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use case, but usually you do things like that simply through ngOnInit or some other of the [angular life cycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

You can only bind events that are actually existing on that html element (without the on, so onclick becomes click).

You tried to to a custom event:

```
@Output('autoLoad') initEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

This event is belongs to your `somethingComponent` component, you can only use this event on that component. So your html code should be:

```
<something class="LG_global-wrap" (autoLoad)="arrayContains('a string')"></something>
```

The component having that html is then listening on that event. Obviously the handler function has to be on that component too:

```
export class somethingElseComponent {
  public arrayContains(needle) {
    console.log('needle: ', needle);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the function call to ngOnInit, and it will run without any event necessary:

```
ngOnInit() {
    arrayContains(needle);
}
```

If you want to call it from template for some reason, the EventEmitter can be listened to in the parent template, not on the same level where it emits. So you would need to add it in parent html:

```
<something (autoLoad)="arrayContains('a string')"></something>
```